# How to send an input as a parameter to a route? Symfony-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, input, parameters, routes

This is my situation: I'm using Symfony and Bootstrap and I have this input text field:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Max amount">
</div>
```

What i want to do is send what the person writes in that field as a parameter to this route:

```
<a href="{{ path('_filtered') }}" class="btn bg-danger">Filter</a>
```

How can i do that? I have tried doing this:

```
<a href="{{ path('_filtered', {'parameter': amount}) }}" class="btn bg-danger">Filter</a>
```

amount being the input ID. But it doesn't work, and after looking for hours i couldn't find a solution so any help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Update:
HTML:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}


{% block panelhead %}
Publicaciones<br>
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href="{{ path('_altaPubli') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Publicacion</a>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" placeholder="Maximo personas">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coste" placeholder="Maximo coste">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Pais:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" id="sel1">
    {% for publicacion in publicaciones %}
            <option>publicacion.pais</option>
    {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label for="sel2">Provincia:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker">
    {% for publicacion in publicaciones %}
            <option>publicacion.provincia</option>
    {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label for="sel3">Localidad:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker">
            {% for publicacion in publicaciones %}
            <option>publicacion.localidad</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endif %}
<a href="{{ path('_filtradas') }}" class="btn bg-danger" id="2">Filtrar</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cantidad').click(function() {
            var inputData= $('#cantidad').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "{{path('_filtradas')}}",
                data: {
                    'inputData': inputData,
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block panelbody %}
<tbody>
<div class="row-fluid">
    {% for publicacion in publicaciones %}

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="mark-pers">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div>
                        <img src="{{ asset('uploads/fotos/' ~ publicacion.path)  }}" width="240" height="160"/>
                    </div>

                    {{ publicacion.usuario }}
                    <a href="{{ path('_mostrarPublicacion', {'id': publicacion.id}) }}">{{ publicacion.descripcion }}</a></td>
                    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

                        {% if publicacion.usuario.id == user.id %}
                            <a href="{{ path('_modificarPublicacion', {'id': publicacion.id}) }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if publicacion.usuario.id == user.id or is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                            <a href="{{ path('_eliminarPublicacion', {'id': publicacion.id}) }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></a>
                        {% endif %}
                        <br/>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
</tbody>
{#</table>#}
{% endblock %}
```

Controller:

```
    /**
 * Lists all Publicacion entities.
 * @Route("/home/publicacionesFiltradas", name="_filtradas")
 */
public function filtrar(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $publicaciones = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Publicacion')->findAll();
    $inputData = $request->get('inputData');
    dump($inputData);
    return $this->render(':default/publicacion:publicacionesFiltradas.html.twig', array(
        'publicaciones' => $publicaciones,
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
        'cantidad' => $inputData,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Get your data to be sent as a parameter
var inputData= $('#amount').val();

    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST', // It can either be POST or GET depending on what you want to do.
          url: "{{path('_filtered')}}",
          data: { 
              'inputData': $inputData,              
          },
          success: function(msg){
            // Perform your actions here. 
          },

        });
```

});

and in the controller I would get that data:

```
$inputData = $request->get('inputData');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: By the way, the code where you get the data should be inside of an event.
$('#amount).click(function(){// get data here}):

Comment: It has been of great help, thanks a lot, but i'm having the problem that after $inputData = $request->get('inputData'); $inputData has a null value. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller as well as the view?

Comment: Just did, note that it now has some spanish words, hope that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT do this WITHOUT front-end manipulations:

First, server outputs your code/template/page the way you've coded it, and ONLY THEN user enters something in the input field. At this time only front-end/browser handling is possible, which is basically JavaScript.

So you have to create an event, which will look after the field and if something is entered, pass it to you button, href...

So, don't try to code it in your template with php/html. Use script, which will work after page is loaded. See **Gerardo Soriano** answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I believe the function click does not fit your needs. Try this:
$('#cantidad').focusout(function(){// Everything stays the same});
I think that focusout will be called after an user has input some data and clicks somewhere else.
Let me know if it works

Comment: Still the same. And the focusout part says: "Unresolved function or method focusout()"